# Google Cloud Run deploy on demand services

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I have a question about how to implement a specific workflow on cloud run.
I developed a back-end microservices deployed on cloud run.
Now i have other python project with docker file, that i have stored into google cloud bucket.
I would like to know, how I can create a new cloud run istance from this docker image into bucket, from a rest api using python.
How I could do this?

Thanks

Comment: You want to do something similar to "gcloud run deploy" in python, right?

Comment: Yes…..I want to do this. I need to run deploy on demand from Python  flask api and stop the new istance always on demand

Comment: I can understand you want to deploy a new service on demand, but you lost me when you said to "stop the new instance". Do you talk about instances or service?

Comment: Sorry man,  I mean stop the service created on demand from flask api

Answer (score 2):

You don't have any client library to create or to delete the service. You can use the discovery API or you can use the [API directly](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/rest#rest-resource:-v2.projects.locations.services).

Pick the correct endpoint (it depends on your location) and invoke the correct endpoint. The Service body is the JSON(yaml) that you have on the console when you deploy a service, you can take inspiration from there.

You can also use the `--http-log` with the `gcloud` command to see the exact API calls (endpoint and body) to reproduce it in your code.

---

Just a word on a service: you can't "stop it". You can delete it.

Comment: Thanks man, but I have a question: in the body of post request to create service, I have to pass the yaml content converted to json format. Right? Why I not found this spec into google documentation? There is some example to study?

Comment: Yes, that the correct way to achieve this.

Comment: Thanks man....last question. With the api i have seen that i can create a job into cloud run, but there is a way to pass a parameter in this case? Example passing to string that job use as value into process.

Comment: You are talk about Cloud Run Jobs? Correct?

Comment: Yea man, I mean this

Comment: That's the problem for now. I already provided the feedback to the Google Cloud engineering team: it's not possible to provide parameters/env vars after deployment. To achieve that with the preview version, you have to redeploy the service with the correct parameter. In the GA (in the next month I hope) you will be able to provide parameters.

Comment: Ok but if I understand I could be deploy a job defining specific values?

Comment: Yes, you can!!!

Comment: Ok, so the process is always the same of service. To create a job I have to set a yaml file convert to json into the post request